How to know if you've caught a pokemon in the catching screen in Pokemon Go
How do I know if I've caught the Pokemon I just tapped on in the catching screen?
Is it the little icon above the CP that says the Type?

There will be a Pokeball icon near the Pokemon's name if you've already caught it.


is it the same on Samsung?

This kind of feature is not platform related, it should be the same on every device
